# Will the nested transactions be rolled back when the root one rolls back?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, transactionscope, rollback

In this code..

```
public static TransactionScope CreateTransactionScope(bool createNew = false)
{
    return new TransactionScope(
        createNew ? TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew : TransactionScopeOption.Required,
        new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted });
}
```

---

Actually, in this one...

```
using (TransactionScope rootScope = CreateTransactionScope())
{
    using (TransactionScope nestedOne = CreateTransactionScope())
    { nestedOne.Complete(); }

    using (TransactionScope nestedTwo = CreateTransactionScope(true))
    { nestedTwo.Complete(); }

    // No committing, rollback 'rootScope'.
}
```

What transactions will be rolled back along with the root one - will it be only `nestedOne` or both `nestedOne` and `nestedTwo`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

nestedOne will join the root scope, so if the root scope will rollback, nestedOne will be roll back as well, but not nestedTwo which is a seperate transaction.

like you have the "RequireNew" option that seperate the transaction from the enclosing transaction you can have the "Suppress" option that stops the transaction for that scope.

Take a look at the following list from MSDN that gives a great lesson about transactions behaviour.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152(v=vs.90).aspx